# .htaccess for static to wordpress conversion

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file for wordpress blog -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I convert html website into Wordpress blog. I want to redirect my static html and htm pages to wordpress posts.

How and what will be htaccess format.

i.e.

```
Old URl: http://mywebsite.com/saarclaw/pakistan/companies_act.htm 
New URL: http://mywebsite.com/saarclaw/pakistan/the-companies-ordinance-1984.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your wordpress rules, add these, one for each of your pages:

```
RewriteRule ^aarclaw/pakistan/companies_act.htm$ /saarclaw/pakistan/the-companies-ordinance-1984.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Also, please tell, how to do following- 1) how to redirect all post of one directoy into single page? i.e. here /saarclaw/pakistan/ all pages to  htm pages to the-companies-ordinance-1984.html page.